# how to connect to zk9500 with ZKLibrary

Tags: php, zkteco

I have zk9500 device for fingerprint reader and I looking for tutorial for connecting / operate with PHP.

In SDK and Documentation is not very clear for me, I have though about connecting with Web Assembly but I know nothing about that, and after learning it for little while I still don't understand the main concept and not found solution for my case.

I found library **[ZKLibrary](https://github.com/kamshory/ZKLibrary)** and for now is still wondering how to connecting to my zk9500, because I cannot find documentation about the IP and PORT in zk9500,

this is the simple sample code from the library

```
<?php
require 'zklibrary.php';

$zk = new ZKLibrary('127.0.0.1', 4370); // I cannot find this IP and Port configuartion
$zk->connect();
$zk->disableDevice();

$users = $zk->getUser();
var_dump($users)
$zk->enableDevice();
$zk->disconnect();

?>
```

Maybe anyone know how to find the IP and Port, or any suggestion for working this to be working

Thank you.

Comment: hi, were you able to connect to device? because in my case i looking for same thing difference is i need to connect from python and most examples in python are for networkbased but not usb based device

Comment: I only able connect using the SDK, many SDK from google but not all have the .exe file for running the testing, and I don't see any python in the SDK

Comment: you were using php right and i did not see any for php as well so i wnated to know did you switched to other or did you find soln. for php that may be usable for me as well

Comment: I just found a library, and maybe you not clear with my question, I also cannot connect to my device using the library because no documented IP address or how to get it

Comment: The sample code you have posted is the wrong one. The scanner works with a USB port, not the network port. Your code may work with zkteco attendance devices, not with scanners. Find the library for fingerprint scanners.

Comment: hi @Ravanan thank you, I cannot find any library that use USB port for PHP, do you have any suggestion.?

Comment: I am also trying to connect the device through PHP but am unable. If you have any solution please let me know.